# Get thumbnail by ID in Drupal 6, display thumbnail on iPhone/Android

Tags: iphone, android, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I'm building an iPhone/Android mobile application that is supposed to be a mobile version of the existing Drupal 6 based website. Services module is used to provide web services interface to the app. I'm fetching the list of blog posts in JSON format via Drupal Views, where a blog post looks something like the this:

```
{"nid" => "12090",
 "node_data_field_large_thumb_field_large_thumb_fid" => "16746",
 "node_type" => "blog",
 "node_revisions_body "=> "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>",
 "node_title" => "Lorem ipsum",
 "node_created" => "1302883976"}
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to display the post's thumbnail using its ID. Is there something in Drupal (maybe a module) that will allow me to use thumbnail ID in the following way:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/thumbnail/300x200/16476">
```

Or perhaps some other established way of doing this? I have zero experience with Drupal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify the fields to output in Views, you can choose what to display for the image. you can chose the **fid** (which you probably did), or choose to displayt the path, or even the themed image.

In the **Views** admin, in the **Fields** box, click on the image field to show its properties, and then change the format.